# Unusual logical inconsistency observed in my R code

Tags: r, debugging, logical-operators

something to learn/keep in mind.

Looking to tips to avoid such mistakes.

While writing a big(ish) `R` code to go through many data files and creating a data summary, I wanted to use:

```
File_data$name[p] %in% nr_counter$NAME
```

This should basically check if the character (a name) in `File_data$name[p]` belongs to the `NAME` column of `nr_counter`. But to my surprise the command cannot work it out. I can't find out why. The only lead I got is that the test:

```
File_data$name[p] == "Bohuslav Diviš"
```

returns FALSE, when it should be TRUE (the text is "Bohuslav Diviš").

Here are further code outputs I am uploading that test the type of the objects and some logical mismatches from my console

```
> File_data$name[p] %in% nr_counter$NAME
[1] FALSE
> File_data$name[p]
[1] "Bohuslav Diviš"
> nr_counter$NAME
[1] "qwert"          "Bohuslav Diviš"
> nr_counter$NAME[2]
[1] "Bohuslav Diviš"
> File_data$name[p] == nr_counter$NAME[2]
[1] FALSE
> "Bohuslav Diviš" %in% nr_counter$NAME
[1] TRUE
> "Bohuslav Diviš" == File_data$name[p]
[1] FALSE
> File_data$name[p] == "Bohuslav Diviš"
[1] FALSE
> typeof(File_data$name[p])
[1] "character"
> typeof(nr_counter)
[1] "list"
> typeof(nr_counter$NAME)
[1] "character"
> nr_counter
            NAME        COUNTRY COUNTER
1          qwert          asdfg       1
2 Bohuslav Diviš Czechoslovakia       1
> as.character(File_data$name[p]) %in% as.character(nr_counter$NAME)
[1] FALSE
```

Can it be a problem due to the special letter 'š' in the name?

I think so. Based on the following changes I made:

```
> File_data$name[p] = "Bohuslav Divis"
> nr_counter$NAME[2] = "Bohuslav Divis"
File_data$name[p] %in% nr_counter$NAME
[1] TRUE
```

I thought that if I revert back to the name with 'š', then this logical test should come out as FALSE if the special letter alone causes problem. This is the result:

```
> nr_counter$NAME[2] = "Bohuslav Diviš"
> File_data$name[p] = "Bohuslav Diviš"
> File_data$name[p] %in% nr_counter$NAME
[1] TRUE
```

As one can see above, FALSE was not obtained. Thus now I am confused to how to do the test in my code running over lots of data.

Thanks for patience, hope this observation tickled your creative centres.

Cheers...

Comment: Can you check the `Encoding()` of the character vectors? If they are encoded different there is a chance that they will not be bit-wise equal. You can also set the `Encoding(x) <- "latin1"` to make sure they both have the same encoding. Not sure if this will help or not.

Comment: @AdamSampson - both are 'latin1'

At the moment, I am not using the %in% command, hard coding it with loop to bypass this

Comment: I am unable to duplicate the issue with the data given. When I copy your variables from stackoverflow into R the code you have works. This indicates there is some problem other than the values. To recreate the data I tried: `p = 1; File_data <- list(); File_data$name[p] <- c("Bohuslav Diviš"); nr_counter <- list(); nr_counter$NAME <- c("qwert","Bohuslav Diviš")`

Comment: I could not do anything about it myself....
In the end I committed a sin: I used Excel to compute that column. Damn